# Get the Failure/Error line from rspec output in after(:each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, appium

I'm using TestRails to log failures in our automated test suite. Example failures have output like this:

```
Failures:

  1) can click on the Photos button after logging in
     Failure/Error: login.signin_btn.click
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/kkrzeminski/TestApp/Appium/Common/pages_helper.rb:36:in `click'
     # ./test_1_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I can grab the exception using `example.exception` in the `after(:each)` block in my `spec_helper`, as well as the backtrace, but what I'm really interested is that line beginning with `Failure/Error:`. I can't seem to find a way to get that string. It would be handy for logging the reason for test failure in TestRails, as just the exception and the backtrace aren't very descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is a custom formatter for your CI environment. The [protocol](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Formatters/Protocol) for RSpec formatters provides an [`example_failed`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Formatters/Protocol#example_failed-instance_method) hook which will give you the example object.

You can then use [`Example`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example) and [`Notifications`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Notifications) objects to gather the information you are desire.

Comment: To add to what Aaron said, the `Failure/Error` line is exposed as the first line from `message_lines` on this formatter notification: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb#L162-L167